# struggling with listview-onitemclicklistener

Tags: java, android, listview, onitemclicklistener

i am following [this](http://www.go4expert.com/articles/parse-json-data-android-application-t30169/) tutorial and i got it to work. made one class that display categories and second class to display books of that category. i am struggling with `OnItemClickListener`...if someone could explain to me where do i add the `OnItemClickListener` in the code (the **`MainActivity.java`** ) from the tutorial , it would be a great help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Tutorial](http://www.go4expert.com/articles/parse-json-data-android-application-t30169/) you have mentioned, has `MainActivity extends ListActivity`. In this case, you could use inside MainActivity itself

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    // Do what ever you want
}
```

Comment: i was trying to do something like that in onCreate all this time...but i was getting a "The method is not applicable for the arguments ....and so on " error

Comment: :) pleasure... It happens... Try to look more into callback methods available for ListActivity

Comment: My anwer is correct also. He just used wrong import.

Comment: you are right @Divers, i got it to work with your code as well.
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in onCreate method of your Activity put:

```
getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
   public void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //here you go. 
    }
});
```

Comment: i am getting this error "The method setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) in the type AdapterView<ListAdapter> is not applicable for the arguments (new OnItemClickListener(){})"... i did try something like that from this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-listview-tutorial/ and got the same error